# How do I match the '@' character in a syntax file?

Tags: regex, vim, syntax

I want to match words that begin with `@`, using this line:

> syn match xamlName "\%x40\w*" contained

or this line:

> syn match xamlName "@\w*" contained

or this line:

> syn match xamlName "\@\w*" contained

or pretty much any line that will work, as those three do not (at least, not in vim73).

What is the correct line to match, for example, `@test` in this text:

```
            ~td: `args.sample.third_party_account`

        ~div .left #nice_div @name $string
    Items
```

Comment: Can you post an example "random" file?

Comment: What would you like the output to look like?

Comment: @JanNielsen:  It's a `syntax` file -- I'll use the match to change the color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a top level syntax rule, which may contain the xamlName file, then leave out the "contained" argument:

```
:syn match xamlName /@\w\+/
```

Else Vim will only try to match your syntax item within another syntax item and not at the top level.

Also note, by itsself, this won't highlight anything. You need to link the xamlName syntax item to a defined highlighting name, e.g. `hi def link xamlName ErrorMsg`

Comment: At it happens, I do have it contained in another syntax item... argh!  It's missing from the other declaration! <sigh>  Okay, I added it, and now my original try of `"@\w*"` works.  I wasn't able to get your syntax of `/@\w\+/` to work at either the contained level nor the top level, though.  +1 for helping me catch my missing declaration, though.  :)